# How to detect and connect to a Wifi network programmatically using Apple SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, wifi

I wonder how can I detect and make a connection to a Wifi network programmatically just like the WifiFoFum app does in Apple Store. This app has been approved and recently updated so there must be a legal way of doing it.
If anybody knows any way of doing it please post a code snippet... even if it is an undocumented API call and would probably be rejected by Apple. I just need to know if it can be done and how.
Thanks

Comment: I have seen a wifi port scanner named "Snap" which is available in the AppStore. I'm very curious to how it works as well.

Comment: Hi, Did you finally achieve that? I have similar needs to access programmatically to a specific wifi network.

Comment: Did you find the way to do it?

Comment: I'm wondering the same.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing but sadly those features are only available in private APIs which Apple does not allow anymore at all! So there is no official way of finding or connecting to networks!